# VBA delete specific shapes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I made a VBA macro for MS powerpoint 2011 on Mac. I'm really not into VBA but managed somehow to let 12 shapes appear on the screen with text but I basically took this here as a starting point. My modifications are probably not the best way to do this but it does the job.

But now I would like to create another macro which lets the shapes, named from `Dim Shp As Shape` to `Dim Shp11 As Shape`, disappear or delete once the macro was executed. I tried a lot of things but always got errors. Some help here is highly appreciated..

I was also not able to find out how I can make an Add-In out of a macro in MS PowerPoint 2011 for Mac. Does someone perhaps have an idea?

Thank you so much!

***Clarification:***

The idea behind this macro is, to display the color values that should be used in a ppt and I thought it could be nice to toggle these colors on and off - no matter in which slide you are.

So, again: The code looks horrible but i'm not a big programmer ;)

```
Sub show_ci_colors()

'PURPOSE:Create a Text Box Shape and Reformat it
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim Sld As Slide
Dim Shp As Shape
Dim Shp1 As Shape
Dim Shp2 As Shape
Dim Shp3 As Shape
Dim Shp4 As Shape
Dim Shp5 As Shape
Dim Shp6 As Shape
Dim Shp7 As Shape
Dim Shp8 As Shape
Dim Shp9 As Shape
Dim Shp10 As Shape
Dim Shp11 As Shape

'ERROR HANDLING
If ActivePresentation.Slides.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "You do not have any slides in your PowerPoint project."
    Exit Sub
End If

Set Sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

'Create shape with Specified Dimensions and Slide Position
    Set Shp = Sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=-80, Top:=20, Width:=60, Height:=40)

    Set Shp1 = Sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=-80, Top:=62, Width:=60, Height:=40)

    Set Shp2 = Sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=-80, Top:=104, Width:=60, Height:=40)

    Set Shp3 = Sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=-80, Top:=146, Width:=60, Height:=40)

    Set Shp4 = Sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=-80, Top:=186, Width:=60, Height:=40)

    Set Shp5 = Sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=-80, Top:=230, Width:=60, Height:=40)

    Set Shp6 = Sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=-80, Top:=272, Width:=60, Height:=40)

    Set Shp7 = Sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=-80, Top:=314, Width:=60, Height:=40)

    Set Shp8 = Sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=-80, Top:=356, Width:=60, Height:=40)

    Set Shp9 = Sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=-80, Top:=398, Width:=60, Height:=40)

    Set Shp10 = Sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=-80, Top:=440, Width:=60, Height:=40)

    Set Shp11 = Sld.Shapes.AddShape(Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
    Left:=-80, Top:=482, Width:=60, Height:=40)



'FORMAT SHAPE
 'Shape Name
    Shp.Name = "My Header"

'No Shape Border
    Shp.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp1.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp1.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp2.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp2.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp3.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp3.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp4.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp4.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp5.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp5.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp6.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp6.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp7.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp7.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp8.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp8.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp9.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp9.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp10.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp10.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp11.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Shp11.Shadow.Visible = msoFalse

'Shape Fill Color
    Shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(4, 110, 151)                   'BLUE 700
    Shp.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(4, 110, 151)                   'BLUE 700

    Shp1.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(6, 166, 227)                  'BLUE 300
    Shp1.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(6, 166, 227)                  'BLUE 300

    Shp2.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(133, 199, 226)               'BLUE 100
    Shp2.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(133, 199, 226)                'BLUE 100

    Shp3.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(23, 152, 131)                 'GREEN
    Shp3.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(23, 152, 131)                 'GREEN

    Shp4.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(254, 201, 5)                     'YELLOW
    Shp4.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(254, 201, 5)                     'YELLOW

    Shp5.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(189, 57, 47)    'RED 700
    Shp5.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(189, 57, 47)    'RED 700

    Shp6.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(225, 92, 80)   'RED 300
    Shp6.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(225, 92, 80)   'RED 300

    Shp7.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(237, 140, 52)   'ORANGE
    Shp7.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(237, 140, 52)   'ORANGE

    Shp8.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(64, 64, 64)   'GREY 700
    Shp8.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(64, 64, 64)   'GREY 700

    Shp9.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(84, 84, 84)   'GREY 600
    Shp9.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(84, 84, 84)   'GREY 600

    Shp10.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(189, 189, 198)   'GREY 300
    Shp10.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(189, 189, 198)   'GREY 300

    Shp10.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(189, 189, 198)   'GREY 300
    Shp10.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(189, 189, 198)   'GREY 300

    Shp11.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(238, 238, 238)   'GREY 200
    Shp11.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(238, 238, 238)   'GREY 200


'Shape Text Color
    Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    Shp11.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(64, 65, 65)

'Text inside Shape
    Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Blue 700" & Chr(10) & "4 / 110 / 151"
    Shp1.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Blue 300" & Chr(10) & "6 / 166 / 227"
    Shp2.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Blue 100 " & Chr(10) & "133 / 199 / 226"
    Shp3.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Green" & Chr(10) & "23 / 152 /131"
    Shp4.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Yellow" & Chr(10) & "254 / 201 / 5"
    Shp5.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Red 700" & Chr(10) & "189 / 57 / 47"
    Shp6.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Red 300" & Chr(10) & "225 / 92 / 80"
    Shp7.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Orange" & Chr(10) & "237 / 140 52"
    Shp8.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Grey 700" & Chr(10) & "64 / 65 / 65"
    Shp9.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Grey 600" & Chr(10) & "84 / 84 / 84"
    Shp10.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Grey 300" & Chr(10) & "189 / 189 / 189"
    Shp11.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Grey 200" & Chr(10) & "238 / 238 / 238"


'Center Align Text
    Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    Shp1.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    Shp2.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    Shp3.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    Shp4.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    Shp5.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    Shp6.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    Shp7.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    Shp8.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    Shp9.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    Shp10.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    Shp11.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter

'Vertically Align Text to Middle
    'Shp.TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle

'Adjust Font Size
    Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8
    Shp1.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8
    Shp2.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8
    Shp3.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8
    Shp4.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8
    Shp5.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8
    Shp6.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8
    Shp7.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8
    Shp8.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8
    Shp9.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8
    Shp10.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8
    Shp11.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 8


'FONT STYLE DELETED
'Adjust Font Style
' Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Verdana"L

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete shapes in a collection, you need to count backwards so this example shows how to delete all shapes from slide 1 of the active presentation:

```
Dim iCounter As Integer
For iCounter = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.Count to 1 Step -1
  ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(iCounter).Delete
Next
```

You can of course add checks to decide which type/name of shape is to be deleted.

Next, if you want to use the macro in an add-in in PowerPoint:mac 2011, save it as a .ppam file and then load it using **Tools**/**Add-Ins...** You might also want to add a menu to be able to access the features of your add-in and you'll need to use **CommandBars** for that on PowerPoint:mac 2011 This will get you started:

```
Dim oMenuBar
Dim oMenu As CommandBarPopup
Dim oCtrl As CommandBarControl
Dim iTools As Integer

' Get the position of the native PowerPoint tools menu (English only)
iTools = Application.CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar.Controls("Tools").Index

' Create a new menu
Set oMenuBar = Application.CommandBars.ActiveMenuBar
Set oMenu = oMenuBar.Controls.Add(type:=msoControlPopup, Before:=iTools, Temporary:=True)
With oMenu
  .Caption = "My Menu"
  .Enabled = True
End With

' Add a control
Set oCtrl = oMenu.Controls.Add(type:=msoControlButton)
With oCtrl
  .Caption = "My Tool"
  .OnAction = "MyMacro"
End With
```

If this helps, please vote for the solution :-)

Comment: Thank you for that. It works but only if i'm on the first slide plus, it deletes also a textbox.

Wouldn't it be possible to do sth. like Shp1 .Delete and repeat that for all the other shapes too? :)

Comment: If you set a reference to Shp1 then Shp1.Delete will work.  W/o seeing the code you're using, it's hard to say how to fix it, though.  You could, when creating the shape, give it a name then later Slides(x).Shapes("YourShapeName").Delete (where x is the index of the slide you want to work with)

Comment: Thank you. Well, the the code just looks horrible. I'm not really a programmer :) The idea behind this macro is, to display the color values that should be used in a ppt and I thought it could be nice to toggle these colors on and off - no matter in which slide you are. I will post the code I have above..